# Deploy multiple applications from same project

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

How can I deploy multiple applications from same or different language/runtime originating from a single project in google cloud app engine?

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: sorry for the misleading language. Just edited.

Comment: Also check if that wouldn't be in violation of section 3.3 (d) of the Terms of Service: https://cloud.google.com/terms/

Comment: Think not, because I dont intend "to simulate or act as a single Application, Account, or Project (respectively) or otherwise access the Services in a manner intended to avoid incurring Fees;". I would still want to deploy it as two different apps, with different versions accessible with different URLs. 
Secondly, google cloud does provide the facility to deploy multiple services on a project:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/microservices-on-app-engine

Comment: OK. But you need to give a lot more details. Do you want multiple services? Multiple apps? What's your app doing? What are the difficulties? Otherwise the answer is simple (and likely useless): Yes - you just re-write/adjust your app code as needed :) But note that depending on your app specifics it might not be possible or it might require a lot of work. For example sharing the datastore across multiple apps require extra work, task enqueueing across apps is impossible.

Comment: Have you tried creating different modules for same project?

Comment: Is this about Java or Go? You've tagged it as both.

Answer (score 37):

### Deploying Multiple Services to Google Cloud App engine.

Create the following files  in the app root directory

Create app.yaml file with content:

```
runtime: nodejs14
service: default
```

Create myserviceone.yaml file with content:

```
runtime: nodejs14
service: myserviceone
```

Create myservicetwo.yaml file with content:

```
runtime: nodejs14
service: myservicetwo
```

Deploy using command

```
gcloud app deploy --project your_project_id app.yaml myserviceone.yaml myservicetwo.yaml
```

This will deploy the default service as well as my service one and my service two. Check out your cloud console.

You can access them using:

https://myserviceone-dot-yourProjectID.appspot.com/ or
http://myserviceone.yourProjectID.appspot.com/

https://myservicetwo-dot-yourProjectID.appspot.com/ or
http://myservicetwo.yourProjectID.appspot.com/

Comment: Thanks for sharing, this really helped me.

Comment: Any specific reason why google doesn't allow to specify multiple services (comma seperated or other seperator) in same app.yaml file to deploy code to multiple services?

Comment: what about composer.json and vendor? Should there be a single vendor repo common to all services, located at the top level?

Answer (score 25):

Today, App Engine has a one-to-one correspondence with a Google Cloud Console project. You cannot deploy multiple "apps" in the same project. However, you might still be able to do what you want depending on your application(s).

App Engine has the concept of "services," which are independent aspects of your application. Your App Engine app can have many services and each service can have its own language/runtime and even be on different App Engine environments.

You could have say a Python service on App Engine standard environment that is used to serve your simple Flask site, could have service that serves an API written in Java 8 on the Standard Environment, and could have yet another service in say Node.js running in the App Engine flexible environment.

Your "default" service is defined in your `app.yaml` file. Your other services can be defined in different folders and can have either an `app.yaml` with their service definitions or you could name them something else like `backend.yaml`. See [this simple Python project](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard/firebase/firenotes) for the layout of the configuration files.

For more conceptual information about services on App Engine, [see Microservices Architecture on Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/microservices-on-app-engine).