# How to change the target URL in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm trying to do App Engine with endpoints.  When I deploy the app, the server takes the project ID of the other basic App Engine project I have. In the trace I found that the target project, target service, target version, and target url all are that of the basic App Engine project.

The trace is as follows:

```
target project:  [testniit1]
[INFO] GCLOUD: target service:  [default]
[INFO] GCLOUD: target version:  [20171024t130444]
[INFO] GCLOUD: target url:      [https://testniit1.appspot.com]
```

([Image of the trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncBVl.png))

But my actual project ID / project URL is `endpoint2-2.appspot.com`.

How can I change the default/target URL?

Answer (score 18):

First of all, App Engine as of writing has a one-to-one correspondence between app and project. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46047030/1161743 for more details.

However you can declare services within App Engine that will give you what you want.

In app.yaml:

```
service: foo-bar
```

This will generate:

```
[INFO] GCLOUD: target url:      [https://foo-bar-dot-project-name.appspot.com]
```

Comment: How do I set it up such that instead of `https://foo-bar-dot-project-name.appspot.com` it would be https://foo-bar.project-name.appspot.com

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that is possible. You should setup your own custom domain to point at whatever App Engine gives you.

Answer (score 1):

From what I have seen, the project ID is a unique identifier that can be found at https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard. Make sure your project is selected, then look under "Project Info" at the top left.

After you have that info, you can set the project in your Google Cloud SDK Shell by typing in the command `gcloud config set project <projectID>`

Official CLI documentation: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/set

Comment: This is wrong. All this does is change to a different project on the console, this **does not** change the project id nor the target url.

Answer (score 0):

Check you [`appengine-web.xml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref) - the `testniit1` should be defined there in `<application>_your_app_id_</application>` tag.

End-points should be a part of your path, eg:

```
https://YOU_APP_ID.appspot.com/SOME_OPTIONAL_PREFIX/ENDPOINT_NAME
```

Also you can use modules, then the url could looks like:

```
https://ENDPOINT_MODULE.YOU_APP_ID.appspot.com/SOME_OPTIONAL_POSTFIX
```

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy to different service to get this done.

https://VERSION_ID-dot-SERVICE_ID-dot-PROJECT_ID.REGION_ID.r.appspot.com

you can add your service in yaml file if it is node project.
Or add it in pom file if it is JAVA.

More [info](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy)